# Why does the command, 'react-native run-android' not work on my Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, android-studio, react-native

I'm trying to run a react-native app on `Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS`, but the command `react-native run-android` doesn't work.

I've followed every tutorial I could find, every `stackoverflow` post even remotely related, yet each time I get to this error:

> error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
> warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
> info Installing the app...
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create parent directory for lock file /home/davidnichol/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.2-all/dvufqs6kielxeao781pmk5huj/gradle-6.2-all.zip.lck
> at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:43)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create parent directory for lock file /home/davidnichol/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.2-all/dvufqs6kielxeao781pmk5huj/gradle-6.2-all.zip.lck

I'm using android studio

Please send help!

Comment: Make sure you have an android emulator and launch it

Comment: I have 2 set up, they run fine but they won't load any apps because of the error mentioned.

Comment: Check emulator connected via command:  `adb devices`. I think your problem is emulator, not Linux OS